# javascript/html - Textarea in popup/modal is not editable

Tags: javascript, html

I want to have a popup modal in which users can select an image and add an alternative text for this image. The popup is showing as expected, (and users can select images and upload them) however the textarea is not editable.

The button to open the modal:

```
<button type="button" onclick="openModal()">Add image</button>
```

The popup:

```js
function openModal() {
  var imageTemplate = document.getElementById("tpl-image");
  imageTemplate.style.display = "flex";
}

function closeModal() {
  var imageForm = document.getElementById("tpl-image");
  imageForm.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="openModal()">Add image</button>


<section class="popup-img" id="tpl-image" style="width:100%;height:100%;background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);position:absolute;top:0%;display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;display:none;z-index:2000;">
  <section class="popup-img-content" style="width:500px;height:300px;background-color:white;border-radius:10px;text-align:center;padding:20px;position:relative;">
  <button type="button" onclick="closeModal()" class="close" style="position:absolute;top:0;right:14px;font-size:42px;transform:rotate(45deg);cursor:pointer;border-width:0px;background:none;">+</button>
  <form method="post" id="image-form" class="image-form" data-url="/url/to/post/request/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h3>Select image to upload:</h3>
    <input type="file" name="image_file" id="image_file">
    <textarea name="alttext_image" id="alttext_image" class="js-question-text autosize" tabindex="1" style="word-break:break-word;display:block;width:100%;resize:none;" placeholder="Type alternative text for image">  </textarea>
    <button type="button" name="submit_image" id="btn-image-upload">Upload image</button>
  </form>
  </section>
  </section>
```

I already tried the following two options inside the openModal() function:
`document.getElementById("alttext_image").readOnly = false;` and `document.getElementById("alttext_image").removeAttribute('readonly');`. However, both of them did not change anything: If I click on the textarea, nothing happens and I cannot add any text.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This does not appear to be reproducible with what code you have shown so far - https://jsfiddle.net/x49wLpvy/, works fine. So you’ll need to show us a _proper_ [mre] of your issue.

Comment: I was not aware of jsfiddle, but thank you for showing that the root of the problem is probably somewhere else in the code!

Comment: This probably your problem here. your button doesn't have end tag `</button>`
`<button type="button" onclick="openModal()">`

Comment: @StacksQueue My bad, I forgot to copy-paste the end tag. I have updated the question so that the end tag is there. (Unfortunately this does not change the problem).